# Are there any good Python Modules For Sending Hundreds of Bots?

Tags: python

Im trying to find a python module that I can use to send hundreds of bots to a website and click buttons. (something like selenium). If there is a way in selenium to have it send lots of bots out that would be good too. currently I have only been able to do it with one bot and headless selenium.

Comment: It's not python but blaze meter is handy when testing a website. Or jmeter

Comment: I think multithreading would be a good option for this:https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can host the bots using a Google Cloud Container, and create as many instances of them as you need on demand, and even setup with a database/custom API to send in parameters as well!

I've done this before for a business solution following this great tutorial:
https://dev.to/googlecloud/using-headless-chrome-with-cloud-run-3fdp

Also as somebody mentioned in the comments, depending on your use case multithreading could also be very useful.